# How do I record stream with rtmpdump?

Tags: flash, streaming

What I need is for somebody with experience in rtmpdump commands to translate how to use one of the streams. 
Here is how a stream info comes in provide list:

```
<item>
<title>TVR 1</title>
<link>rtmp://cdn1.us.spicetvnetwork.zone:1935/live?c=5&amp;u=66302&amp;e=1420619579&amp;t=56877e 65b09a0d8a4b80ca4a22ba9307&amp;d=xbmc&amp;i=84307 playpath=mp4:spicetv/ro/TVR1.stream swfUrl=http://static.spicetvbox.com/flash/jwplayer.flash.swf pageUrl="http://api.spicetvbox.com/live/tvr-1" swfVfy=true live=true</link>
<thumbnail>http://www.spicetvbox.com/storage/channels/tvr-1.png</thumbnail>
<epg></epg>
</item>
```

I manage to get this far:

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://cdn1.us.spicetvnetwork.zone:1935/live?c=5&u=66302&e=1420619579&t=56877e65b09a0d8a4b 80ca4a22ba9307&d=xbmc&i=84307" -a "live/" -f "LNX 11,6,602,171" -W "http ://static.spicetvbox.com/flash/jwplayer.flash.swf" -p "http ://api.spicetvbox.com/live/tvr-1" -y "nnnnnn.sdp" -o nnnnnn.flv
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.Failed
```

Please note you will not be able to access the stream yourself as it is locked on each user's IP.

Answer (score 1):

After reading some manual, I managed to make it work. 
For the example above:

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://cdn1.us.spicetvnetwork.zone:1935/live?c=5&u=66302&e=1420619579&t=56877e65b09a0d8a4b80ca4a22ba9307&d=xbmc&i=84307" -a "live?c=5&u=66302&e=1420619579&t=56877e65b09a0d8a4b80ca4a22ba9307&d=xbmc&i=84307" -f "LNX 11,2,202,425" -W "http://static.spicetvbox.com/flash/jwplayer.flash.swf" -p "http://www.spicetvbox.eu/live/tvr-1" -y "mp4:spicetv/ro/TVR1.stream" -o TVR1.stream.flv
```